# In ExactTarget How to Query and compare records with all data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation

I am trying to check the data from particular data extension whether they exist in any other data extension.  How can we compare a data from particular data extension with all other data extensions in ExactTarget? I tried something like this:

```
Select 
ls.SubscriberKey 
from  _Subscribers  ls  
INNER JOIN CTTrigger cs ON cs.EmailAddress = ls.EmailAddress
```

But no result. I have also tried using `_ListSubscribers` but no result. Can  anyone help me out in this? My data extension has email as primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly find matching subscribers in Data Extensions or in the [System Data Views](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) with SQL JOINS.

If you have an Enterprise 2.0 account, All Subscribers is shared by all business units (at the parent level) and therefore needs an `ent.` prefix (if you're in a child business unit)...as do all shared Data Extensions.

```
Select 
s.SubscriberKey 
from ent._Subscribers s  
INNER JOIN CTTrigger t ON t.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress
```

There's no way to check "all other data extensions".  You'll have to name them explicitly.

Comment: Hi Adam i tried a simple query with _subscribers like "Select TOP 5 a.Subscriberkey from _subscribers s " but it doesn't work.I think my account is not an Enterprise 2.0.Where can i check the version number?

Comment: try `select top 5 s.subscriberkey from ent._subscribers s`

Comment: Hi Adam its working  ,so this will query only the subscribers from parent account or will return users from both parent and child?sorry for being burden I am new to Exact target

Comment: Both parent and child.  Subscribers in a 2.0 (which you have) are shared across all business units.

Comment: What if i want them to check only in parent account is there any way?like we are quering  Data extension in parent account like ent.[DE]