# SQL Activity Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Just followed those instructions: https://markus.codes/2017/07/14/how-to-sync-email-changes-from-service-cloud-to-all-subscribers-list

Currently getting the following error. (Using multiple Business Units) The Synchronized Data Extension in the same BU where the Query activity is called 'Contact_Salesforce'

Comment: Try wrapping it like this ent.[Contact_Salesforce]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isnt obvious but synchronized data extension reside at the parent business unit level and are shared through the account.

Changing `Contact_Salesforce` to `ent.[Contact_Salesforce]` should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a multi business unit org to test currently. But if you have an Enterprise 2.0 account and the synchronized data extensions are shared across business units, you may need to prepend `ent.` to the data extension name:

```sql
...
FROM
    ent.Contact_Salesforce as sfdc
...
```

I found this information in this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/116099/36218

Comment: Actually Multi-Org feature is enabled as well. So there are different Synchronized Contacts in different BUs